# How To Embed Google Drive Document (PDF) In Blogger Post?

Tags: iframe, google-drive-api, blogger

I want to embed a pdf document from Google Drive in my Blogger Post.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Select the pdf file you want to embed.
Right click > **Preview** > **More actions** > **Open in a new window**. Now click **More actions** > **Embed item**. Copy the embed code and paste it on your blog post (File must be set **publicly visible** if you want everyone to see this).

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3VnSl89GUNxaXI1NzNrLUZTYWs/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Comment: @SifaturRahman How did you manage to show the PDF to EVERYONE? When I try to do this, there is a warning message saying "Only the owner and explicitly shared collaborators have access"

Comment: @shenkwen in the google drive, **Right Click** >> **Share** >> **Link Sharing** choose **Anyone with the link Can View**

Comment: has the  Embed item option been removed? I dont see in the drop down menu.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid It is still there, may be you are confused with 'More actions', it is the vertical three dot button which can be found at the top right corner after choosing preview.

Comment: Google no longer supports embed link? I'm getting this error: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'getLayoutMap' on 'Keyboard': getLayoutMap() must be called from a top-level browsing context.`

Comment: @SifaturRahman We have to do this changes in "HTML" edit option. It will not work otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

Update in March 2021 for embedding pdf document in blogger or blogspot post. [Right click the PDF document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QKoL.jpg). Click on "**Share**" first, and [choose share with Anyone option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wZIZ.jpg)- by default it is selected to Restricted access. If you wish the document to be accessible to everyone, then Change this from Restricted to Anyone. Next, again Right click the PDF document, and now this time Click on **Getlink**, which will provide you with the url or link to the document which you can paste or link in the blogpost post.