# Displaying PDF file from an EMBED HTML tag fails on Android and iOS based smart phones

Tags: php, android, html, ios, pdf

I am not able to show the PDF Help file from  my web app to the following smart phones:
Android - it just shows an Open button and clicking on does nothing
iOS (iPad or iPhone) - only show the first page of the pdf.

It works fine from Windows 10.   Is there something I am overlooking?

Here is the code:

```
   <?php

        define('ROOT_PATH',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

        define('URL_PATH',"/CMS_Public_2/");


            $help_file="Documentation/CMS_Documentation.pdf";

            $documentation_file_path= URL_PATH.$help_file;


         
   echo <<<_END

       <html>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        </html>

             <embed src=$documentation_file_path type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="900px" />
    _END;
  ?>
```

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf document.

Comment: I am not sure what you are implying with the comment?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand of my simple message,?

Comment: What do you mean a WebView can not display a pdf document?   Is this related to the iOS or Android OS on smart phones?   What is the recommended solution?

Comment: If your Android app does not use a WebView to display the php output then tell what you mean with 'HTML tags fails on Android. I think that Android will not do that but one or other app. Which app on Android? Who displays or should display?

Comment: I use Google Chrome on both the Android and the iOS devices.

Comment: But than your question has not much to do with programming Android apps. You should consult Google instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238412/discussion-between-jack-stein-and-blackapps).

Comment: I am trying to chat with you.

Comment: BY the way - I do not think it is related to Google, the problem shows up with Safari on the iOS device.    I am not programming these devices, I am trying to run a web app on these devices.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching I found the following post  [How To Embed Google Drive Document (PDF) In Blogger Post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164367/how-to-embed-google-drive-document-pdf-in-blogger-post)     and I tried a test of the proposed solution that addresses all the issues I had on iPad, iPhone and Android devices when running the same web application that runs on Windows and shows the PDF Help File.